# Logging from Airflow DAG into separate, custom log file

Tags: airflow, python-logging

We have many python processes that all implement a common logger setup which logs everything to the same file and rotates the file daily.

We recently started switching to using Airflow. Originally we were using BashOperators, but we wanted to start using PythonOperators to take advantage of more of Airflow's functionality. However, when we call our logging setup from a DAG, the logging setup does not seem to get applied. I have tried numerous methods, from calling `our_custom_logging.setup()` at the top of the DAG to putting it in the python callable:

```
def python_callable():
    our_custom_logging.setup()
    run_job()
```

It seems that this still always just ends up in the standard Airflow log location. I am aware of how we can change the Airflow logging config, but we still want those logs to stored and visible in the UI, so ideally we just wanted to add our additional log handling alongside Airflow's. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: What does the setup method do?

Comment: Any latest update on this kind of logging?